# load bearing beam

Tags: beam, support

I need to add a beam to a 28'w x 24'd home.  Do I have to run a beam perpendicular to the floor joists (the 28') or can I run several the 24' parallel to the joints? The home was built with rafters but the floor is sagging slightly in the center.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It’s difficult to believe that your floor joists span 24 feet. I’d guess they span either 8’ or 12’. Can you verify? Also, what size and spacing are the joists?

Comment: Well she does say that the joists are sagging and need a beam for support, so it is quite possible it was done incorrectly originally.  I would hazard a guess that the beam must be perpendicular but will defer to on actual engineer.

Comment: Sorry for the house problems.

Comment: So are you trying to level the floor or the roof or both it is unclear where you want the beam.